# JSF double click on selectOneListBox

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces

I have the following code:

```
 <p:selectOneListbox id="requirementsUrl"
                            value="#{data.data.selectedURL}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{data.data.requirementsDocuments}"
                                itemValue="#{rURL}" />

                        </p:selectOneListbox>
```

The thing that I want to make is when someone clicks twice in the selected item something should happen, so far I have tried this method but it's not working:

```
<f:ajax event="dblclick" listener="#{logic.onDoubleClick}" />
```

Comment: try <p:ajax .../> instead of <f:ajax .../> it's not the same thing

Comment: thant worked thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to change

```
<f:ajax .... />
```

by

```
<p:ajax .... />
```

the first one was used to make update before JSF 2.0 you can read more [JSF - Ajax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_ajax.htm) also our friend Balus C answer a question about it you can follow this post to read it [How does Ajax work on JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485845/how-does-ajax-work-on-jsf)

Hope that helped you.